# $(XY)^*=X^* Y^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Is it true for complex matrices $X,Y$ that
$$
(XY)^*=X^* Y^*?
$$
where $^*$ refers to complex conjugation.  How can we prove this if so?  Thanks!

Note: I am referring to complex conjugation, not the hermitan transpose. The answer below refers to hermitan tranpose.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is defined only using product and sum of entries, and the conjugation preserves both operations for complex field.

Comment: While your question is legitimate, please note that in linear algebra, the standard notation for the complex conjugate of a matrix $A$ is $\overline{A}$. The asterisk notation in almost all cases refers to the conjugate transpose, not complex conjugate.

Comment: If you think about $A,B$ as linear operator on a vector spaces with inner product, then $\langle AB u, v \rangle = \langle Bu, A^*v\rangle = \langle u, B^*A^*v\rangle$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For conjugate transpose it holds $(XY)^*=Y^*X^*$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Edit: For complex conjugation, indeed, $(XY)^*=X^*Y^*$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105172/xy-x-y/2105176#2105176), and the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Generalizations), section "generalisations".

Comment: Op says $*$ denotes the complex conjugation, not hermitian.

Comment: I am talking about complex conjugation not the hermitan transpose. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Both use $*$.

Comment: @Integrals The entries of $XY$ are sums of products, where conjugation is the same as first conjugating and then form the sum of products.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, that makes sense.